# Colorbox after ajax form submit close the colorbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried to submit a form while calling ajax script once i submit the form then the colorbox should close and the response will be displayed in the parent window.

I'm getting the response displayed in parent window, but the colorbox not closing after getting response

MY Jquery :

```
$('#product_cover').live("click", function(e){

        var checked= $('input:checkbox[name=cover_image]:checked').val();
        $.post(baseurl+"ajax_functions/update_product_cover/", {
                    product_cover: checked,
                    product_id:product_id,
                    shop_id :shop_id,
        }, function(response){
        parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
            $('#product_cover_image').html(response);
        });

    });
```

But i have included all the necessary jquery lib files

Tried the below actions:

```
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close()

function closebox() {
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
}
$.colorbox.close();
```

Note : The form is located in ajax paged colorbox and the jquery was placed in that pop up new window only

Comment: Are you opening a new window in javascript? of is it just a jQuery colorbox ajax page with a form on it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 0):

If the form is in a popup window. Place this on the top level or opener:

```
function closeColorbox(){
    $.colorbox.close();
}
```

On the window that has the form on it do

```
$('#product_cover').live("click", function(e){
    var checked= $('input:checkbox[name=cover_image]:checked').val();
    $.post(baseurl+"ajax_functions/update_product_cover/", {
                product_cover: checked,
                product_id: product_id,
                shop_id: shop_id
    }, function(response){
        $('#product_cover_image').html(response);
        window.opener.closeColorbox();
    });
});
```

If the form in just inside of a colorbox ajaxed page you are accessing the same jQuery object. so just do

```
$('#product_cover').live("click", function(e){
    var checked= $('input:checkbox[name=cover_image]:checked').val();
    $.post(baseurl+"ajax_functions/update_product_cover/", {
                product_cover: checked,
                product_id: product_id,
                shop_id: shop_id
    }, function(response){
        $('#product_cover_image').html(response);
        $.colorbox.close();
    });
});
```

You just need to make sure that the colorbox ajaxed page isn't reloading/loading a second jquery or colorbox when the page is loaded.

Comment: @AaruKarthiga Could you please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? There isn't much else I can do to help you without more information.

Comment: In your fiddle you are using `$('#cboxClose').close();` please change to `$.colorbox.close();`

Comment: Can you add your code to open the colorbox ajax form page in the question?

Comment: @AaruKarthiga You need to remove the last comma in the data object for your `$.post`. & also what browser are you using?

Comment: Using chrome and firefox